# Run multiple scripts from a single script

Tags: php, include, simple-html-dom

I have a script which generates an RSS feed, I call the script from cron and it generates an XML file.

What I would like to do is write a single script that I can call from cron, but that script in turn calls multiple scripts which generates multiple RSS feeds.

I tried doing:

```
<?php
  include('delicious-tags.php');
  include('delicious-user.php');    
?>
```

But I get the error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot redeclare file_get_html() (previously declared in /home/danvelox/public_html/simple_html_dom.php:65) in <b>/home/public_html/simple_html_dom.php</b> on line <b>80</b><br />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Change every instance of including/requiring simple_html_dom to [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) / [require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php).

This will keep PHP from trying to re-include the whole library and attempting to redefine all the functions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the same function is defined in both files. PHP doesn't like it when this happens.

If the function does the same thing move it to a seperate file.

If this function is declared in other files included by the files you are including it means there is a flaw in your including structure. While you could just use `include_once` or `require_once` it really means that you should probably move the inclusion of the library files to a higher level file so they don't collide in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

```
exec("php-cli delicious-tags.php");
exec("php-cli delicious-user.php");
```

Comment: If it's a cron, it's already using PHP CLI (at least, it should)